# IE11 table responsiveness issues with SVG elements inside <td>

Tags: html, css, svg

Hey guys I'm trying to create a table with a SVG element inside hat looks like something below

```
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1</td>
    <td>Row 1</td>
    <td>Row 1</td>
    <td>Row 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 2</td>
    <td>Row 2</td>
    <td>Row 2</td>
    <td>Row 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="arrow-row">
    <td>
      <svg version='1.1' class="svg-triangle" xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' viewBox='0 0 100 35' enable-background='new 0 0 100 35' xml:space='preserve'>
        <polygon points='0,0 100,0 50,30' />
      </svg>
    </td>
    <td>
      <svg version='1.1' class="svg-triangle" xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' viewBox='0 0 100 35' enable-background='new 0 0 100 35' xml:space='preserve'>
        <polygon points='0,0 100,0 50,30' />
      </svg>
    </td>
    <td>
      <svg version='1.1' class="svg-triangle" xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' viewBox='0 0 100 35' enable-background='new 0 0 100 35' xml:space='preserve'>
        <polygon points='0,0 100,0 50,30' />
      </svg>
    </td>
    <td>
      <svg version='1.1' class="svg-triangle" xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' viewBox='0 0 100 35' enable-background='new 0 0 100 35' xml:space='preserve'>
        <polygon points='0,0 100,0 50,30' />
      </svg>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My issue is that it works as expected on Chrome

[image]

But on IE11 it looks like this

[image]

Here is the fiddle to test https://jsfiddle.net/8eubhk6c/2/

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: try giving the svg elements width and height attributes or styles.

Comment: @RobertLongson giving it a fix heigh does solve it, however that will no longer make the svg triangle responsive.

Comment: so give it a percentage height.